# highlight html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting

How can highlight html elements, with javascript, for inspection of html and css selectors linked to that element. The highlighting could be just a change of borders or background (so it doesnt break the layout) and a tool tip revealing the html element and css selectors conected to that element.

Comment: How about using the developer-tools in your browser, all of them have it these days?

Comment: If you want a custom solution you have to be more specific about where you are stuck.

Comment: Have you attempted this on your own? I would give it a try first then post when you cannot solve a more specific problem. Here is a good place to start: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$('div, a, span, p').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({ "border": "2px solid red" });
    console.log($(this));
},function(){
    $(this).css({ "border": "none" });
});
```

I'd use Firebug (FF) or Console (Chrome) to inspect elements though.

Comment: You should at least mention that you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you just need to be using something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or Developer tools (F12) for IE.  Every browser has them.

They let you highlight anything and play around with any css selectors.  Absolute must tools for the web developer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a tool like Firebug? This does an excellent job, showing the source of the page and highlighting elements on mouseover. Also, in recent versions of the three major browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) there is a built-in inspector. In FF 10, right click anything and click Inspect Element. In Chrome, the process is the same. In IE 9, press F12, then Ctrl+B and click the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

If you use google chrome, you can enable developer tools in View / Developer / Developer Tools.
When choosing this menu, on the bottom part of the browser will apear a frame with a menu, (here you should click the Elements button).
Under this menu you'll see the source of your document.
When hovering on certain tags (ie:  ) in the browser the element will be highlighted, and you'll be able to see properties of the highlighted tag.